# Awk to compute average ignoring outliers -for a segmented file

Tags: bash, awk, average, outliers

I have data file (data.txt) that look like this,

```
0.01667 20.53
0.01667 6.35
0.01667 6.94
0.01667 7.07
0.01667 8.06
0.01667 8.10
0.01667 8.25
0.01667 8.71
0.01667 9.31
0.02500 20.19
0.02500 6.35
0.02500 6.92
0.02500 7.07
0.02500 8.08
0.02500 8.09
0.02500 8.24
0.02500 8.70
0.02500 9.26
0.03333 19.89
0.03333 6.33
0.03333 6.90
0.03333 7.07
0.03333 8.07
0.03333 8.09
0.03333 8.22
0.03333 8.70
0.03333 9.22
0.04167 19.65
0.04167 6.34
0.04167 6.87
0.04167 7.07
0.04167 8.03
0.04167 8.08
0.04167 8.19
0.04167 8.69
0.04167 9.19
0.05000 19.40
0.05000 6.32
0.05000 6.85
0.05000 7.06
0.05000 8.02
0.05000 8.09
0.05000 8.16
0.05000 8.71
0.05000 9.15
0.05833 19.12
0.05833 6.29
0.05833 6.84
0.05833 7.04
0.05833 8.01
0.05833 8.11
0.05833 8.16
0.05833 8.71
0.05833 9.11
0.06667 18.84
0.06667 6.29
0.06667 6.82
0.06667 7.05
0.06667 7.98
0.06667 8.11
0.06667 8.14
0.06667 8.71
0.06667 9.06
0.07500 18.57
0.07500 6.29
0.07500 6.80
0.07500 7.06
0.07500 7.97
0.07500 8.10
0.07500 8.13
0.07500 8.71
0.07500 9.02
```

Column 1 is the time at which the measurements in column 2 were taken. I need to average the values in column 2 for each time given in column 1 and output the value of the time and the mean value for that time. I am able to do the avearge using the following awk code

```
awk '{if($1<0)$1=0}
    {
        sum[$1]+=$2
        cnt[$1]++
    }
    END {
    #     print "Name" "\t" "sum" "\t" "cnt" "\t" "avg"
        for (i in sum)
            printf "%8.5f   %6.2f   %6d   %6.3f\n", i, sum[i], cnt[i], sum[i]/cnt[i]

    }' data.txt  | sort -n -k1 > avgFile.txt
```

Note that I also output some other things just so I can check that am doing the right thing. As you can see the data for each time slot contains outliers, I need to remove these. I have tries to select say data collected at 0.01667 to some file temp.txt and I have the following awk code that correctly removes the outlier

```
awk 'BEGIN{CNT=0} {ROW[CNT]=$0;DATA[CNT]=$2; 
    TOTAL+=$2;CNT+=1;} END{for (i = 0;i < NR; i++){if ((sqrt((DATA[i]-(TOTAL/NR))^2))<((TOTAL/NR)*30/100)) 
    {print ROW[i] ;}}}' temp.txt
```

But I need to do this in the original code so that I remove this outlier for each time that has one before I compute the mean of the values in column 2

Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your problem isn't with awk, but that you need to detect outliers while reading the data. How would you e.g. detect the first point as an outlier? This isn't trivial, see e.g. http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.109.1943.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Benjamin, In this case I used standard deviation where I consider a value in the data that has more than 30% divergence from the average, to be an outlier, which I thought would be enough ground to remove such a value from average computation. Thanks for the link to the study, I am not yet able to download the full manuscript. I will read it once I have the full paper

Comment: You may experiment with simple methods. Like reading all values for a specific time into an array, averaging the data, then computing the deviation for each point removing any that are greater than some threshold you come up with. Example for `.01667`, the avg is `9.25` if you set your threshold at `4`, you would eliminate your outlier. The same logic seems to work for all outliers.

Comment: Hi David, I have been trying to do something similar to that as you see in my second piece of code in which I use the fact that if a particular value has more than 30% divergence from the average, I remove it. The problem I am facing right now is how to implement this in my code where I do both selecting the data for a specific time and then remove the outlier and finally compute the average. My awk skill are still at infancy

Comment: @malandisa I am no `awk` expert, but a simple bash script can handle it easily. Simply use a `while loop` and add values with the same time to a tmp array, process the array to remove outliers, then get avg, mean and std dev of remaining values, unset the array and move to next time. If I get a chance, I'll write an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This calculates the averages, then deletes outliers, then recalculates the averages after the outliers were removed:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    vals[$1][$2]
    sum[$1] += $2
    cnt[$1]++
}

END {
    div = 0.3
    for (time in vals) {
        ave  = sum[time] / cnt[time]
        low  = ave * (1 - div)
        high = ave * (1 + div)
        for (val in vals[time]) {
            if ( (val < low) || (val > high) ) {
                print "Deleting outlier", time, val | "cat>&2"
                sum[time] -= val
                cnt[time]--
            }
        }
    }

    for (time in vals) {
        ave = (cnt[time] > 0 ? sum[time] / cnt[time] : 0)
        print time, sum[time], cnt[time], ave
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
0.05000 56.04 7 8.00571
0.07500 62.08 8 7.76
0.04167 56.12 7 8.01714
0.03333 56.27 7 8.03857
0.01667 56.44 7 8.06286
0.06667 55.87 7 7.98143
0.02500 56.36 7 8.05143
0.05833 55.98 7 7.99714
Deleting outlier 0.05000 6.32
Deleting outlier 0.05000 19.40
Deleting outlier 0.07500 18.57
Deleting outlier 0.04167 19.65
Deleting outlier 0.04167 6.34
Deleting outlier 0.03333 6.33
Deleting outlier 0.03333 19.89
Deleting outlier 0.01667 6.35
Deleting outlier 0.01667 20.53
Deleting outlier 0.06667 6.29
Deleting outlier 0.06667 18.84
Deleting outlier 0.02500 20.19
Deleting outlier 0.02500 6.35
Deleting outlier 0.05833 6.29
Deleting outlier 0.05833 19.12
```

Is that what you were looking for? It uses GNU awk for true 2-D arrays.

Comment: Ed!! Thank you! This works perfectly. Indeed this is what I needed and I have learned a lot from this. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome, if this is the answer you wanted then please click on the check mark next to it to indicate that.

Comment: I really have to look more into awk. That's much simpler. However, I can't figure out where you are showing the averages without the outliers? Maybe I just misread the question. Like for time `0.01667` I get an average without the outlier of `7.84875`. I get the same with manually calculating as well?

Comment: The line `print time, sum[time], cnt[time], ave` is printing the averages after the outlier value(s) are removed by `sum[time] -= val` and count of values is decremented by `cnt[time]--`. My calculation finds 2 outliers for `0.01667` (`6.35` and `20.53` since the original average of ALL values is `9.25778` so those 2 values are less than 70% of and greater than 130% of that respectively) so if your calculation only found one then that'd explain why the end results are different. The OP didn't state what the algorithm was to identify an outlier, so I took a guess.

Comment: The OP did say in a comment though `if a particular value has more than 30% divergence from the average, I remove it.` so when I used 30% in my calculations (`div = 0.3`) I didn't pull it out of thin air, I just wasn't sure if the way I used it was exactly what they had in mind.

Comment: Indeed what I wanted was if the value diverges from the mean by greater than 30%, I need it removed. Now I am facing a challenge when I try to run my script in linux mint. It doesnt work correctly. On my mack it gives me the right thing that I need but on linux mint it just gives zeros,I am wondering if this could be due to the version of gawk used or what? It shows that count for a particular time is 0. I just cant figure out what the problem is. I see that on my mac I have gawk 4.1.1 installed via macports while on my linux mint I have gawk 4.0.1

Comment: I ahve just figure that it is actually seeing all values as outliers. I dont understand why? especially because it works on mac. and on both the mac and the linux mint I am running gnu awk

Comment: Add some printfs, reduce the code to the part that you don't understand the bahavior of, etc. ... All the usual stuff you'd do to debug a program. It's less than 20 lines, it won't take you long. FWIW my money's on your input file having changed. Maybe there's some control-Ms at the end of lines or something?

Comment: I have figured out that its a problem that has to do with gawk 4.0.1 Went to another computer running ubuntu with this version of gawk, same problem but then on to another running ubuntu still but with gawk 4.1.1, no problem, the code works well

Comment: I can't imagine why that would be. The only thing gawk-specific about that code is the use of 2D arrays and that was introduced in gawk 4.0 and would give you a syntax error on any awk that doesn't support 2D arrays. It's also very simple, basic code so it's not doing anything unusual. Are you SURE its not some difference between your input files (or between the code files themselves) on the different computers? AFAIK it simply cannot be the gawk versions causing the problem. Try `cat -v` on all files to look for control-Ms, and `dos2unix` or similar to remove them if present.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I told you when I got time I would write a quick script (turned out it wasn't that quick) This removes the outliers and returns the average of the cleaned array. You can implement a standard deviation if needed. Let me know if you have questions.:

```
#!/bin/bash

## generic error/usage function
function usage {
    local ecode=${2:-0}
    test -n "$1" && printf "\n %s\n" "$1" >&2
cat >&2 << helpMessage

usage:  ${0//*\//} datafile

This script will process a 2-column datafile to provide average, 
mean and std. deviation for each time group of data while removing
outlying data from the calculation. The datafile format:

    time    value
    0.01667 20.53  <- outlier
    0.01667 6.35
    0.01667 6.94
    ...

Options:

    -h  |  --help  program help (this file)

helpMessage

    exit $ecode;
}

## function to calculate average of arguments
function average {

    local sum=0
    declare -i count=0
    for n in $@; do
        sum=$( printf "scale=6; %s+%s\n" "$sum" "$n" | bc )
        ((count++))
    done
    avg=$( printf "scale=6; %s/%s\n" "$sum" "$count" | bc )
    printf "%s\n" "$avg"
}

## function to examine arguments a remove any outlier
#  that is greater than 4 from the average.
#  values without the outlier are returned to command line
function rmoutlier {

    local avg=$(average $@)
    local diff=0
    for i in $@; do
        diff=$( printf "scale=6; %s-%s\n" "$i" "$avg" | bc )
        [ "${diff:0:1}" = '-' ]  && diff="${diff:1}"            # quick absolute value hack
        [ "${diff:0:1}" = '.' ]  && diff=0                      # set any fractional 0
        if [ $((${diff//.*/})) -lt 4 ]; then
            clean+=( $i )                                       # if whole num diff < 4, keep
        else
            echo "->outlier: $i" >&2                            # print outlier to stderr
        fi
    done
    echo ${clean[@]}                                            # return array
}

## respond to -h or --help
test "${1:1}" = 'h' || test "${1:2}" = 'help' && usage

## set variables
dfn="${1:-dat/outlier.dat}"     # datafile (default dat/outlier.dat)
declare -a tmp                  # temporary array holding data for given time
ptime=0                         # variable holding previous time (flag for 1st line)

## validate input filename
test -r "$dfn" || usage "Error: invalid input. File '$dfn' not found" 1

while read -r time data || [ -n "$data" ]; do               # read all lines of data

    if [ "$ptime" = 0 ] || [ "$ptime" = "$time" ]; then     # if no change in time
        tmp+=( $data )                                      # fill array with data
    else
        echo "  time: $ptime  data : '${tmp[@]}'" >&2       # output array to stderr

        ## process data
        clean=( $(rmoutlier ${tmp[@]} ) )                   # remove outlier
        echo  "  time: $ptime  clean: '${clean[@]}'" >&2    # output clean array
        avgclean=$( average ${clean[@]} )                   # average clean array
        printf "  avgclean: %s\n\n" "$avgclean" >&2         # output avg of clean array

        unset tmp           # reset variables for next time
        unset clean
        unset avgclean

        tmp+=( $data )      # read first value for next time set
    fi

    ptime="$time"           # save previous time for comparison

done <"$dfn"

## process final time block

echo "  time: $ptime  data : '${tmp[@]}'" >&2

## process data
clean=( $(rmoutlier ${tmp[@]} ) )
echo  "  time: $ptime  clean: '${clean[@]}'" >&2
avgclean=$( average ${clean[@]} )
printf "  avgclean: %s\n\n" "$avgclean" >&2

unset tmp
unset clean
unset avgclean

exit 0
```

**usage:**

```
./outlier.sh  datafile
```

**output:**

```
$ ./outlier.sh dat/outlier.dat
  time: 0.01667  data : '20.53 6.35 6.94 7.07 8.06 8.10 8.25 8.71 9.31'
->outlier: 20.53
  time: 0.01667  clean: '6.35 6.94 7.07 8.06 8.10 8.25 8.71 9.31'
  avgclean: 7.848750

  time: 0.02500  data : '20.19 6.35 6.92 7.07 8.08 8.09 8.24 8.70 9.26'
->outlier: 20.19
  time: 0.02500  clean: '6.35 6.92 7.07 8.08 8.09 8.24 8.70 9.26'
  avgclean: 7.838750

  time: 0.03333  data : '19.89 6.33 6.90 7.07 8.07 8.09 8.22 8.70 9.22'
->outlier: 19.89
  time: 0.03333  clean: '6.33 6.90 7.07 8.07 8.09 8.22 8.70 9.22'
  avgclean: 7.825000

  time: 0.04167  data : '19.65 6.34 6.87 7.07 8.03 8.08 8.19 8.69 9.19'
->outlier: 19.65
  time: 0.04167  clean: '6.34 6.87 7.07 8.03 8.08 8.19 8.69 9.19'
  avgclean: 7.807500

  time: 0.05000  data : '19.40 6.32 6.85 7.06 8.02 8.09 8.16 8.71 9.15'
->outlier: 19.40
  time: 0.05000  clean: '6.32 6.85 7.06 8.02 8.09 8.16 8.71 9.15'
  avgclean: 7.795000

  time: 0.05833  data : '19.12 6.29 6.84 7.04 8.01 8.11 8.16 8.71 9.11'
->outlier: 19.12
  time: 0.05833  clean: '6.29 6.84 7.04 8.01 8.11 8.16 8.71 9.11'
  avgclean: 7.783750

  time: 0.06667  data : '18.84 6.29 6.82 7.05 7.98 8.11 8.14 8.71 9.06'
->outlier: 18.84
  time: 0.06667  clean: '6.29 6.82 7.05 7.98 8.11 8.14 8.71 9.06'
  avgclean: 7.770000

  time: 0.07500  data : '18.57 6.29 6.80 7.06 7.97 8.10 8.13 8.71 9.02'
->outlier: 18.57
  time: 0.07500  clean: '6.29 6.80 7.06 7.97 8.10 8.13 8.71 9.02'
  avgclean: 7.760000
```

---

**Addendum: write time & avg to file**

Below is an updated bit of the script that will output the `time` and `clean average` to a file (default: dat/outlier.out). Only the lines containing the 'output file name' `ofn` have changed. (you can pass any output filename you want to the script as the 2nd argument) So the new `usage:` would be: `outlier.sh input_file output_file`:

```
## set variables
dfn="${1:-dat/outlier.dat}"     # datafile (default dat/outlier.dat)
ofn="${2:-dat/outlier.out}"     # output file (default dat/outlier.out)
declare -a tmp                  # temporary array holding data for given time
ptime=0                         # variable holding previous time (flag for 1st line)

:> "$ofn"                       # truncate output file

## validate input filename
test -r "$dfn" || usage "Error: invalid input. File '$dfn' not found" 1

while read -r time data || [ -n "$data" ]; do               # read all lines of data

    if [ "$ptime" = 0 ] || [ "$ptime" = "$time" ]; then     # if no change in time
        tmp+=( $data )                                      # fill array with data
    else
        echo "  time: $ptime  data : '${tmp[@]}'" >&2       # output array to stderr
        printf "  time: %s  " "$ptime" >>"$ofn"             # output array to file

        ## process data
        clean=( $(rmoutlier ${tmp[@]} ) )                   # remove outlier
        echo  "time: $ptime  clean: '${clean[@]}'" >&2      # output clean array
        avgclean=$( average ${clean[@]} )                   # average clean array
        printf "  avgclean: %s\n\n" "$avgclean" >&2         # output avg of clean array
        printf "  avgclean: %s\n" "$avgclean" >>"$ofn"      # output avg of clean array to file

        unset tmp           # reset variables for next time
        unset clean
        unset avgclean

        tmp+=( $data )      # read first value for next time set
    fi

    ptime="$time"           # save previous time for comparison

done <"$dfn"
```

**outlier.out:**

```
time: 0.01667    avgclean: 7.848750
time: 0.02500    avgclean: 7.838750
time: 0.03333    avgclean: 7.825000
time: 0.04167    avgclean: 7.807500
time: 0.05000    avgclean: 7.795000
time: 0.05833    avgclean: 7.783750
time: 0.06667    avgclean: 7.770000
```

Comment: David, thank you for your script. Now I am trying to figure out how I can output the time and the average for that time to a file instead of printing all the things to the screen. This is good for my learning bash scripting but its taken me so long but still cant get it right.

Comment: Thank you David. Now it does output to a file as alright. The only downside though is that it is quite slow. For a file with about 1010 lines it take about 2 minutes to process, that's quite slow. Is there a way to make is faster or that's the best it can do? Please test it on this file... https://www.dropbox.com/s/1scfvhz6aom3jvj/Data.txt?dl=0

Comment: the -24.000 is supposed to be converted to a 0.00 somehow.